# Can two characters occupy the same square if one is prone?

Tags: dnd-4e

Can two players characters occupy the same square if one is prone?
- *assuming they are both medium size*

And what happens when the prone character stands up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes they can.**

Page 205 of the *Rules Compendium* reads:

> **Ally:** A creature can enter an ally's space, but it can end its move in an ally's space only if that ally is prone.
>
> ...
>
> **Prone Creatures:** A prone creature that ends up in the same square as another creature has two main options for moving itself out of that square: crawl or stand up.

When the prone character stands up he gets a free shift (well it's part of the move action he is already taking) into an adjacent square (*Rules Compendium*, p.250).

Comment: I agree, but looking at the `Rules Compendium`, it's the section about standing up as a `Move Action`. Is there anything explicit on the effects if there are two characters, one of which is `Prone`, e.g. are they both `Squeezed` ?

Comment: As there appears to be no rule for this, both are normal (there would have to be an exception that states "x happens when creatures share a space"). P205 of the RC allows moving into an ally's space explicitly.

Comment: Ah ha, that's spot on ... "only if the ally is prone"